# Как получить список пользователей базы данных?

Tags: delphi, interbase, база-данных

Как получить список пользователей базы данных?

Comment: Список подключенных пользователей или вообще список всех существующих в системе аккаунтов?

Comment: kirelagin, лучше всех аккаунтов в системе.

Answer (score 2):

> Interbase SQL Server supports several
> user authentication methods:
>
> - Classic Authentication Scheme - users and passwords are common for all
>   the bases and are stored in Interbase
>   system database - **admin.ib** (isc4.gdb).
> - Embedded User Authentication - users and passwords are stored in the
>   client's database. Such a scheme
>   protects databases from direct copying
>   of client's database or substitution
>   of admin.ib on server.

+

> В isc4.gdb/admin.ib находится основная
> таблица USERS, в которой хранится имя
> пользователя, пароль, и другие
> параметры.

+

> среди системных таблиц баз данных ODS
> 11.2 всегда присутствует таблица RDB$USERS. Это эквивалент таблицы
> USERS из admin.ib

Русские цитаты [отсюда](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/ib75eua.htm).